# SQL Server: Query Performance Profit Calculation

Tags: sql-server, performance, controlling

I recently tuned some queries by adding an index and am now trying to asess if the overall situation on that table got better.

I have captured some metrics from  `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. The **first chart** shows the difference between **the number of overall** `user_seeks` (scans, lookups and user_updates (writes)) for that specific new index. The **second chart** simply **subtracts** `user_updates` from all the reads on that index. Looking at those figures alone I can clearly see, that the index is more written to than actually read from.

However, this index particularly helped two monitoring queries hitting the server every minute 24/7. Before I added this index those queries did a clustered index scan. By looking at the metrics for the clustered index I can clearly see that the number of scans dropped by the same rate the new index now gets seeked (720 seeks per 6 hour window and thus 2.880 seeks (or former clustered index scans) per day.

Thank you for being patient and reading all this....now to my question. In what way am I able to calculate the volume of MB writes to my new index are causing. I'd like to do a comparison between the IO (in MB) with all that table scans and the IO afterwards with seeking and maintaining the new index.

So that's the calculation I did:

```
Read IO Table Scan             79.977 Reads / 128 = 765,45 MB

-Read IO Index Seek                15 Reads / 128 = 0,12 MB

= Read IO Savings per query    765,33 MB

Read IO savings per day        765,33 MB * 2.880 = 2.152 GB
```

-**Writing new index per day    26.000 writes * 49 Byte per row written = 1.274.000 Byte**

```
Overall benefit per day          2.152 - 754.000/(1024^3) = 2.152 - 0,0011= 2.151,99 ?????
```

My savings on read IO are quite straightforward as I collected this information during query tuning. However, how can I calculate (or do an educated guess) on the IO overhead for writing on that index?  I know that I am doing approximately 26.000 writes per day. The index has the following structure:

```
 [2 KEYS] column1 {datetime 8}, column2 {datetime 8} [3 INCLUDES]  column3 {bit 1}, column4 {bigint 8}, column5 {int 4} [SECRET COLUMNS (Clustered Key)] [3 KEYS] column6 {bigint 8}, column7 {bigint 8}, column8{int 4}
```

So I guess the leaf level record has 49 byte (summing up all that numbers). Has it? How could I guess the intermediate levels?

Anyhow...(more on the direction of the "educated guess") in your experience does that really matter as I am saving me from scanning the table anyway and doing this in a regular fashion?

Thank you very much for reading and sharing your insights into query tuning profit calculation with me.

[image: Index Performance]

Answer (score 0):

check out the dmv sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats, it will provide information about how many pages SQL Server is having to move around and read in order to fulfill queries/updates. This gives a better view of actual IO. Also take a good look at the columns on Waits, it will let you know if index maintenance is causing problems for other queries.